# Access 2007 CInt Query Issue

Tags: sql, ms-access

There is probably a pretty basic answer to this question, but I'm pulling my hair out trying to resolve my issue. I'm using Access 2007.

My query is shown below:

```
SELECT Pricing.*
FROM OrderReceipt_be 
INNER JOIN Pricing ON CInt(OrderReceipt_be.[Pricing Table Option Code]) = Pricing.ID 
WHERE OrderReceipt_be.[PO_Number] = PONumber();
```

For whatever reason, the [PO_Number] field is stored as text against my key which is a long int. This is why I'm trying to convert it to an integer.

However, when I run my query I get the error

> "Compile error. in query expression CInt(OrderReceipt_be.[Pricing
>   Table Option Code]) = Pricing.ID".

I've done some basic research and it seems like the most common issue is that I'm missing a reference library. Howver, having gone through the entire list, I don't see any references that are tagged as "Missing" so it must be something else. I've also tried disabling and re-enabling all enabled reference libraries to see if that helps, but so far nothing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: IDs are usually Long Int, so you want `CLng` instead of `CInt`. But that's probably not causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you can have codes of *Null*, try:

```
SELECT Pricing.*
FROM OrderReceipt_be 
INNER JOIN Pricing ON Val(Nz(OrderReceipt_be.[Pricing Table Option Code])) = Pricing.ID 
WHERE OrderReceipt_be.[PO_Number] = PONumber();
```

or try the reverse conversion:

```
SELECT Pricing.*
FROM OrderReceipt_be 
INNER JOIN Pricing ON OrderReceipt_be.[Pricing Table Option Code] = CStr(Pricing.ID) 
WHERE OrderReceipt_be.[PO_Number] = PONumber();
```